# CSS solution for pattern outside of text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style setup a section of a website with a pattern running to each side of certain pieces of text.  You an see a screenshot that I took from the PSD file here --> http://screencast.com/t/84RCLRdSZT with red arrows pointing to the areas in question that I am finding difficult to solve.

Any idea how to go about this?

Here is what I am starting with:

```
<div class="box">
    <h2>Some text here</h2>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  background:yellow;
}

h2:after,h2:before{
  content:"";
  border:5px double purple;
}
```

here is the fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/HerrLoop/g63LB/1/

As you can see, the stripes are vertical, instead of horizontal as you can see in my initial screenshot.

Comment: updated with some code to start with

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite perfect and requires you set a fixed width on the before/after elements (best I can think of is to use JavaScript if responsive is required), but here goes:

```
h2{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
h2:after,
h2:before{
    content:"";
    margin:0px 20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right:0px;
    height:5px;
    width:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/g63LB/2/

**Edit**

This is *a little bit* more responsive, but still gets kind of cut off at small sizes and looks disproportional at others:

```
.box {
    width:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
h2{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
h2:after,
h2:before{
    content:"";
    margin:0px 20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right:0px;
    height:5px;
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/g63LB/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try the solution described here: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/legends-and-headings/

The quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g6EL9/):

```
h2{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
h2:before, h2:after {
    content: "";
    border: solid #000;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
h2:before { margin: 0 .5em 0 -50%; }
h2:after { margin: 0 -50% 0 .5em; }
```